# PHP How to compute longitude, latitude with km

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to do location based search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615403/how-to-do-location-based-search)
>   [Getting similar longitude and latitude from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951056/getting-similar-longitude-and-latitude-from-database)

I have a dating PHP application working with MySQL database where users enter their location and based on it, other profiles are shown.

Structure of table `cities`:

```
int id PK
int country_id FK
varchar(50) name
float longitude
float latitude
```

Example entry in table:

```
1 | 1 | New York | 23.20323 | 12.32356
```

And I want to select all cities which have longitude and latitude less then 23.20323 + 50 km, more then 23.20323 - 50km respectively.

The issue here is not a SQL syntax, but the actual radius calculation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13951056/50866

Comment: the size of a unit of longitude varies according to latitude. The nearer the poles, the less physial distance each degree represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're after.

```
//Get your base city location e.g. New York
$base_lat = 12.32356;
$base_lng = 23.20323;

//Get target distance in miles
$target_distance = 31; //50km is approx 31 miles

//Select all cities that are closer than 50km (31 miles)
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$base_lat.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$base_lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$base_lat.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM cities
WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL
AND longitude IS NOT NULL
HAVING distance < $target_distance
ORDER BY distance ASC

//Select all cities that are further than 50km (31 miles)
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$base_lat.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$base_lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$base_lat.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM cities
WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL
AND longitude IS NOT NULL
HAVING distance > $target_distance
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: That should do it, I'm going to try it now.

Comment: Only a little mistake, use HAVING instead of WHERE with the distance.

Comment: Good spot, have updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using Great Circle algorithms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Here's how to find distance. You would need to solve the equation for lat2.

distance = ((factor * (lat2-lat1)) ^ 2 + (factor * (lng2 - lng1) * cos(lat2 / 57.3)) ^ 2) ^ .5

Note: factor ~ 69.1 for miles ~ 115.1666667 for km

Comment: This is the correct way to calculate accurate distance. However, unless you need either precise distance, or you are calculating distance over a distance of more than several hundred miles, you can use a simpler form of this equation that will calculate distance on a flat plane.

Comment: Yes, this algorithm is for calculating distance between two long/lat-itudes, but what if I want the opposite? User chooses the radius of 50 km and I want to show him profiles from all the cities which are in this radius of 50 km.

Comment: Calculate the distance, then solve for lat2? Everything is there!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Haversine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).  This is the spherical distance calculation for two latitude / longitude points.